# Delete data row from database using href

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a hard time finding out how to delete the data row in php mysql connect but im not sure about the code though, this is my code:

```
               //URL aka delete button
               <a href ='deluserlist.php?customerNo=$customerNo'>
               //delete from database code
               <?php
               include("../connection.php");  

           $customerNo =$_REQUEST['customerNo'];

           // sending query
           $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cust WHERE customerNo='.$customerNo.'")
           or die(mysql_error()); 

           header("Location: lotres1.php");
               ?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are **deprecated**. Your syntax is susceptible for SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to add the concatenate operator here . Rewrite like this.

```
$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `cust` WHERE `customerNo`='$customerNo'") or die(mysql_error());
```

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: sir, how about the url is it correct? cuz it wont work im having a hard time figuring it out

Comment: It should be like `<a href ='deluserlist.php?customerNo=<?php echo $customerNo; ?>'>`

Comment: Sir, i finally figured it out ,finally after 4 hours of researching thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine PHP and HTML like you did on this line of code. This is incorrect:

`<a href ='deluserlist.php?customerNo=$customerNo'>`

Instead, you should be doing something like this:

`<a href ='deluserlist.php?customerNo=<?php echo $customerNo; ?>'>`

It's also appropriate that you define the `$customerNo` variable *before* you use it as part of your hyperlink.

You should be looking at something like this:

```
<?php
include("../connection.php");
$customerNo =$_REQUEST['customerNo'];
$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `cust` WHERE `customerNo`='$customerNo'") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
<a href ='deluserlist.php?customerNo=<?php echo $customerNo; ?>'>Delete</a>
```

Also, it is highly advisable to use `mysqli_` instead of the deprecated `mysql_` functions.